# If $ x \in \mathbb R^n$ with $\|x\|_\infty < 1$, how to make sense of this quantity $W(x):= \sum_{p=1}^\infty\|x\|_p^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

In some calculations of mine, I've stumbled on the following object, and I'm wondering if its a something recognisable.

---

For $x \in \mathbb R^n$, let $\|x\|_\infty := \max_{1 \le j \le n}|x_j|$, and for $p \in [1,\infty)$, define $\|x\|_p := (\sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|^p)^{1/p}$. Suppose $\|x\|_\infty < 1$ and define
$$
W(x):= \|x\|_1 + \|x\|_2^2+\|x\|_3^3+\|x\|_4^4+\ldots = \sum_{j=1}^n\frac{|x_j|}{1-|x_j|}.
$$

> **Question.** What is known of the function $W$ ? Does the quantity $W(x)$ have any particular meaning ? Has it been studied elsewhere ? Are there any interesting inequalities, formulae, etc. involving it ?

Comment: There is. See my comment to your post.

Comment: Indeed, you right, sorry. So, this is a lot of information. What else do you need ?

Comment: Yes it is alot of (elementary) information. My main question is whether other people have encountered $W(x)$, etc. ? So my question is basically a reference request...